# How can I display "new" or "update" in the view that overrides admin/content/node?

Tags: 6, nodes, views

I have override the page admin/content/node with Views.
The default page of admin/content/node displays "new" for new contents and "updated" for updated contents. How can I display them in the custom View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the "Content: Has new content" field, the same field used from the view that emulates the tracker page.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]